# conditional pipe in bash

Tags: bash, pipe

Is there any built-in way in bash to pipe output further if certain `test` condition is met?

Essentially I want to know if I have to write following function myself or is there some good-practice-already-done way:

```
check() {
    read temp_var
    test "$temp_var" $@ && echo $temp_var
}
```

which would be used as follows:

```
$ echo foo | check == "foo" | cat
=> foo
```

EDIT:
The function above works with all conditions `test` can comprehend, including numerical ones, such as

```
$ echo 42 | check -gt 30 | cat
=> 42
```

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38310/conditional-pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### String matching, optionally including regex matching

`grep` is a standard utility which seems to do exactly what you want:

```
echo foo | grep -x 'foo' | cat
```

I presume that `cat` is meant here as a stand-in for a more complex pipeline.  If it weren't, then the above, of course, simplifies to:

```
echo foo | grep -x 'foo'
```

`grep` is a powerful utility with many options.  See `man grep` for details.

#### Examples

```
$ echo 'foo' | grep -x 'foo' | cat
foo
$ echo 'goo' | grep -x 'foo' | cat
$
```

### More complex tests, including numerical tests

`grep` is good for strings.  For more complex testing, including comparison, inequality, and numerical tests, `awk` is very useful.   For example:

```
$ echo 64 | awk '$1 <= 65' | cat
64
$ echo 66 | awk '$1 <= 65' | cat
$
```

Mathematical expressions can be used:

```
$ echo 8 | awk '2*$1+1 <= 17' | cat
8
$ echo 9 | awk '2*$1+1 <= 17' | cat
$
```

Non-numeric ordering can also be tested:

```
$ echo a | awk '$1 < "b"' | cat
a
$ echo c | awk '$1 < "b"' | cat
$
```

Comment: grep does exactly that, but is only useful with strings - i'd like to be able to use this with numerical and boolean conditions as well. I'll edit my question to mention that

Comment: @Slimior Very good.  In that case, try `awk`.  (see updated answer for an example.)

Comment: how could I not think about `awk`, so simple and elegant - exactly what i was looking for, thanks :)