# Conditional pipe in bash (custom script)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

How can I pipe commands, and inside the script decide if it should break the pipe or not.

It's simmilar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1083840/conditional-pipe-in-bash). But instead of `awk` I'd like to use my own script:

```sh
check_ip | update_bind9
```

`check_ip` should find the external ip (`curl -s ifconfig.co`) and compare it with the IP stored in a file (`~/.ip`).

Here's the main question:

If the IP has changed, `check_ip` should pass the IP through the pipe. If not, it should break the pipe.

Is `check_ip` that breaks the pipe, or `update_bind9` that ignores the call if not called with the IP?

I did some tests, calling: `check_ip | echo "ok"`.

I tried to `exit 0`, `exit 1`, `return true`, `return false`. Tried to `set -e`. No success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All components of a pipeline *start simultaneously* – the second command always will be started no matter what happens in the first command.

So it's the second command which needs to handle empty stdin.

---

But I would say pipes aren't a good choice for this in the first place.

(Maybe you're confusing `|` (pipe) with `||` (boolean OR)? The latter *is* frequently used as a shorter alternative to if/then, e.g. `x || y` will only call y when x fails – and similarly, `x && y` will only call y when x succeeds.)

In general you should use an if/then block. For example, if `check_ip` itself returns 0 (success) when addresses are different but 1 (failure) when they're the same, it would look like this:

```
if addr=$(check_ip); then
    echo "$addr" | update_bind9
fi
```

Alternatively, if update_bind9 can determine the address on its own (without reading stdin), it would be like this:

```
if check_ip_needs_updating; then
    update_bind9
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; Here's the final solution: https://gist.github.com/Falci/73b8298f97a3b1ce55aaaac6844e38a2

Answer (score 3):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1568364/432690) is good. However, if you really need to pipe conditionally then you may find [`ifne`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ifne) useful:

> `ifne` runs the following command if and only if the standard input is not empty.

In your case it will be like `check_ip | ifne update_bind9`.

Most likely `ifne` is not installed in your Linux by default. In my Debian 10 it's in the `moreutils` package. One may think an extra tool is totally excessive, since we can store the output of `check_ip` in a variable and conditionally reuse it, like in the mentioned answer:

> ```
> if addr=$(check_ip); then
>     echo "$addr" | update_bind9
> fi
> ```

The condition may be `[ -n "$addr" ]`, whatever; the important thing is we use a variable. Code like the above may solve your problem but in general there are at least three issues with it. Assume `command1 | command2` instead of `check_ip | update_bind9`. The solution is generalized to:

```
if foo=$(command1); then
    echo "$foo" | command2
fi
```

And then:

1. `foo=$(command1)` will strip all trailing newlines from the output of `command1`. Then `echo "$foo"` (or [`printf … "$foo"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618)) will add exactly one newline character (or some fixed number of them, respectively). For this reason `command2` may not get the exact output from `command1`.
2. `command1` may produce output containing NUL character(s). Bash cannot store NUL in a variable (most shells cannot; zsh can). If NUL appears then `command2` will not get the exact output from `command1`.
3. `command1` may produce a huge or even endless stream, so storing it in a variable may not be possible.

Using a file instead of the variable solves all but the last issue. `command1 | ifne command2` is immune to all three issues.